# Conditional @Scripts.Render in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml page I want to only include certain @Styles.Render bundles depending on the view being displayed.  For example one page may use the jQueryUI library while another may not and I don't want to make the request to download the library if I don't have to.  Can I use a conditional statement in my _layout.cshtml to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use the layout to output the baseline styles/scripts that all views need, and then let the individual views add additional files using a `@section`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `_Layout.cshtml` page add a `@RenderSection`

```
@RenderSection("Page_Styles", required: false)
```

Then in your individual views you can add styles as needed

```
@section Page_Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/style/foo")
}
```

Same idea for scripts

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're better off creating a section in your _layout.cshtml file and then adding content to that section within the view itself. I do something like this for my stylesheets that I don't want to load on every single page:

```
<!-- _layout.cshtml -->
<head>
    <!-- will load on every page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" />
    <!-- will load on only the views where you have @section CSS -->
    @RenderSection("CSS", false)
</head>
```

and then the view:

```
<p>some content</p>
@section CSS { @Styles.Render("~/mystylesheet.css") }
```